# DateTime.Date does not work in HTML5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, datetime

I want do have my DateTime get displayed without the time.

So I use

```
item.AD_Date.Date
```

to cut off the time.

In the Model ( I use MVC) AD_Date is set up like this:

```
public System.DateTime AD_Date { get; set; }
```

But I get my date like this:

```
01.03.2013 00:00:00
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Date` property just returns a `DateTime` with the same date, but at midnight. There's no difference between "a `DateTime` at midnight" and "a `DateTime` just representing a date" (unfortunately).

You need to change how your `DateTime` is *formatted* to only show the date - either by annotating the model or by changing the view.

(Alternatively, use my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) library which has different types for the different kinds of data you want to represent. I haven't tried using it with MVC, but at least for the *formatting* side it should work okay...)

Comment: I see, thanks a lot. I'll accept your answer as soon as I can .

Answer (score 0):

If someone is facing the same problem, here is my *formatting* :

```
 @String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", item.AD_Date)
```